# Regex to search, replace and repeat while there's a match?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to come up with a way to do the following. Given a line of text like (actual Fortran77 code, these declarations begin at column 7)

```
  CHARACTER FOO*1, BAR*2, OTHER*6
```

replace it by

```
  CHARACTER*1 FOO
  CHARACTER*2 BAR
  CHARACTER*6 OTHER
```

I tried this

```
perl -pe '1 while s/^[^*][ ]+CHARACTER[ ]+([a-z-A-Z0-9_]+)\*([0-9]+)(,?)(.*)/      CHARACTER\*$2 $1\n      CHARACTER $4/' foo.f
```

The [^*] bit is intentional (I ignore lines with * at column 1). The output I get is

```
  CHARACTER*1 FOO
  CHARACTER BAR*2, OTHER*6
```

I already see I'll have a problem when only CHARACTER OTHER*6 remains, but I haven't even got there yet. Any help with also this problem would be appreciated.

What should I do to end having the original line replaced by the three lines? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
perl -ple 'if (/^( +CHARACTER) +(\w+\*\d+(?:, *\w+\*\d+)*) *$/) { my $p = $1; $_ = join "\n", map /(\w+)\*(\d+)/ ? "$p*$2 $1" : die("wtf: $_"), split /,/, $2; }' foo.f
```

Man, this looks awful in one line. Formatted:

```
perl -ple '
if (/^( +CHARACTER) +(\w+\*\d+(?:, *\w+\*\d+)*) *$/) {
    my $p = $1;
    $_ = 
        join "\n",
        map /(\w+)\*(\d+)/ ? "$p*$2 $1" : die("wtf: $_"),
        split /,/,
        $2;
    }
' foo.f
```

Comment: This works. There's a lot here for me to dig in. I see my ^[^*] was unnecessary, right? If it must be a sequence of white spaces it can't be an asterisk, duh. Could you give me a reference for this? I mean, the name of the technique/construct/idiom. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @booNlatoT I'm not sure what you're referring to because I don't think this is an "idiom" in particular. If you have questions about specific stuff, I can add explanations.

Comment: Ah, OK. I'm simultaneously learning regex and a minimum of Perl. I thought maybe there was a particular name for this sort of operation I was trying to perform or the particular way you did it.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that came to my mind:

```
# Open file containing the line and loop through lines (I put only one line)
open (INFH, '<', "num.txt");

while(<INFH>){
    @arr = split(',',$_);
    foreach $arrEle (@arr){
        if ($arrEle =~ /CHARACTER/){
            $arrEle =~ s/(\s+)(\w+)(\s+)(\w+)(\*)(\d+)/$1$2$5$6$3$4/;
        }else{
            $arrEle =~ s/(\s+)(\w+)(\*)(\d+)/\tCHARACTER$3$4$1$2/;
        }
        print "$arrEle\n";
    }
}
```

I will update with more details as we discuss in the comments section.

This should work with a line any big, like this:

`CHARACTER FOO*1, BAR*2, OTHER*6, OTHERS*7, OTHERS*8` and so on

Comment: I did not add code to ignore first 6 lines. I assumed the number of declarations in line is not fixed to three. This code can run through entire file but look for Character declarations only(case sensitive). Provide more details and your understanding so that I can provide specific help

Comment: Hi. melpomene's solution worked like a charm. What would be the easiest way to use your method in a command line? Thanks!

Comment: Melpomene's is perfect. My solution isn't much different logically. I jut put it in a way a beginner would understand. You haven't mentioned you needed command line only. I thought a script will be more useful for future use (imagine you want flexibility on the word "CHARACTER" in future, or run once on bulk files, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Your original try is just missing one thing: `^` by default only matches at the beginning of the string, but you want to match at the beginning of a line in the middle of the string.  Change your `s/.../.../` to `s/.../.../m`.

Then you still have to deal with the final substitution; either make the `,` mandatory to match and add a second substitution to deal with the move of the final `*length` or use `/e` and make what's being substituted an expression that does different things when `$3` is empty.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to work my solution a little more. Your comments are appreciated.